# AnyLogic: How can I measure total busy/idle time?

Tags: anylogic

I've been trying to use [Resource Function](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/resource-api.html#resource-functions) `timeInState(ResourceUsageState.USAGE_BUSY, TimeUnits.Hour)` to measure how may hours a machine is busy. This is my approach using HorasExtra as a variable:

[Approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beYkE.png)

I get this error: class com.anylogic.engine.Agent cannot be cast to class horas_extra.M1_Extra (com.anylogic.engine.Agent and horas_extra.M1_Extra are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

I really would like to use the **ResourceFunctions** but I think I'm missing something. I'm most likely not completely understanding this: *"The resources seized by an agent can be accessed via the unmodifiable LinkedList resourceUnits collection of the agent"*.

There's no further information about the topic on AnyLogic nor other websites. Please advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem I'd like to share in case it's helpful for somebody or if there's anything I should be warned.

1. I created a Resource Type `M1_Extra` (this would be my machine).
2. In M1_Extra I defined: a) Variable: `Extra`, b) Function: `fnBusy`, c) Event: `fnUpdate`.
3. In fnBusy: `Extra= timeInState(ResourceUsageState.USAGE_BUSY, TimeUnits.HOUR);`
4. In fnUpdate: `fnBusy();`
5. Then, in Main I created: a) Variable: `HE`
6. In the resourcePool,On Release: `HE = ((M1_Extra)unit).Extra;` And Unit type `M1_Extra`

That way you can acess the Resource Functions. Thanks!

Comment: correct. This is called "Java typecasting", check it out :) Well done